# Opera 11.52 Corrupts Image upload

Tags: php, file-upload, opera, ajax-upload

I have this script which uploads an image. (Ive been using Valums Ajax-Uploader).
It works fine in all browsers.
But in Opera 11.52, the uploaded image gets corrupted.
But when I use PHP's copy() function after the upload, the copied image works fine.

```
copy($upload_dir . $filename, $upload_dir . 'prefix_' . $filename);
```

What could be the reason for this?

Here's a few lines from the upload script:

```
function save($path) {
    if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['qqfile']['tmp_name'], $path)){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

if ($this->file->save($uploadDirectory . $filename . '.' . $ext)){
    copy($uploadDirectory . $filename . '.' . $ext, $uploadDirectory . 'orig_'.$filename . '.' . $ext);
    return array('success'=>true,'filename'=>$filename . '.' . $ext);
} else {
    return array('error'=> 'Could not save uploaded file.' .
        'The upload was cancelled, or server error encountered');
}
```

Comment: I don't think that it's the `copy`-function or Opera's upload algorithm. Can you show your PHP code that handles the file upload?

Comment: updated my post to include a few lines from the upload script

Comment: Does your corrupted image file have an extension before/after the upload? How did you determine that it is corrupted?

Comment: yes the filename is very similar to the copied one except for the prefix that I add. It's corrupted because It doesn't show the photo in the thumbnail and I can't open it with Windows Photo Viewer

Comment: So you don't display the actual image that Opera uploaded, but create a thumbnail version of image with php that you cannot open? If this is the case, open the thumbnail with a text-editor and look for php errors/warnings that may have occurred during it's creation.

Comment: Here's a numbered list of what happens inside the script:  
  
#1. Script uploads image using PHP's move_is_uploaded  
#2. After upload, I create a copy (not thumbnail) of this image in the same directory but I just add the prefix 'orig_'  
3. PHP + jquery displays the image in a div (the image without the prefix)    

Now here's the problem. In step #3, the image displays fine in the browser. But when I navigate to the upload directory to check the image, I can't open it using windows image viewer. The copied image however works fine (the one with prefix).

Comment: That sounds reasonable. You might want to create a minimized working example (working meaning uploading a corrupted image) and create a bug report at https://bugs.opera.com/wizard

Comment: Is the file size of the uploaded image and the file size on your local computer identical?